# Cannot mknod: Function not implemented

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to untar a file in a docker container (as root) which I tar'd on my local computer.

```
tar: ./vsql/dev/fd0u1680: Cannot mknod: Function not implemented
```

Here is the command I'm using:

```
tar -xvzf builds/$(PNAME)/bin/vsql.tar.gz -C builds/$(PNAME)/bin/ || :
```

It works on my local computer when I untar the file?

As far as the message goes mknod stands for make node? Which is when something is trying to be made at the root level. But I'm not trying to make anything at root level? And even if I was, root is running this command.

Comment: Try this as root: `cd /dev ; ./MAKEDEV -v fd0`. If that doesn't do it, try: `cd /dev ; mknod /dev/fd0u1680 b 2 44`.

Comment: @harrymc: Why /dev? That's not where the file is being untarred.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. You are untarring what, and where?

Comment: Are you using Docker on Windows, or another OS? What filesystem does `df -T .` report? And, um, what do you mean by "at root level"? Root privileges? Root directory? Something graph-related?

Comment: @grawity Hi man! I'm using docker with the node:8 image)